How to clear a TextField when it bound to a SwiftData object that isn't optional
Say you have a SwiftData object that doesn't allow optionals:
@Model
class MySet: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var weight: Int
    var reps: Int
    var isCompleted: Bool
    var exercise: Exercise

Then you get from your MySet data a list of these MySets and append them into a State:
  @State var sets: [MySet]

            if let newSets = exercise.sets {    //unwrapping the passed exercises sets
                if (!newSets.isEmpty) {     //we passed actual sets in so set them to our set
                    sets = newSets
                }

And you use that State list in a ForEach and bind the Textfield directly to the data like so:
 ForEach($sets){ $set  in

 TextField("\(set.weight)", value: $set.weight, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

   TextField("\(set.reps)", value: $set.reps,formatter: NumberFormatter())
                                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                                    


}

This will bind whatever is written into the TextField directly to the SwiftData object which is a problem because say you have 50 written and you want to change it to 60 you need to be able to clear the 50 to write the 60 and since the SwiftData object doesn't allow nil it will allow you to remove the 0 but not the 5. Is there anyway to remedy this without having the swiftData object allow optionals for example catching the clearing of the TextField and making it 0 instead of nil when it's cleared?
I attempt to fix it by binding TextField to a new State and using onChanged:
@State private var reps: Int = 0
@State private var weight: Int = 0

                            TextField("\(myset.weight)", value: $weight, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                             
                                .onChange(of: weight) { newWeight in
                                    // Code to run when propertyToWatch changes to newValue
                                    if newWeight != 0 {
                                        myset.weight = newWeight
                                    }
                                }

but now it is changing every single reps and weight of all in sets when I type into one instead of just the one I am typing on

You could bind the TextField to a different variable, which can be an optional. Then use an .onChange handler to update the target value whenever the bound value changes.

I am attempting to do that but now it is changing every single reps and weight of all  in sets when I type into one

And it should be .onChange(of: weight) without the $.

You could try the same technique described in my answer, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78802510/custom-textfield-placeholder-animation/78802796#78802796
The idea is to use text: in the TextField, because
the text is then continously updated. But when you use value:, ie "For non-string types, it updates the value when the user commits their edits, such as by pressing the Return key". So you can adjust the logic to suit your requirements. See textfield

You could create a custom binding which should do the trick:
private func weightBinding(for set: MySet) -> Binding<Int?> {
    Binding<Int?>(
         get: { set.weight },
         set: { value in
             if let value {
                set.weight = value
             }
          }
      )
}

ForEach(sets) { set in
   TextField("\(set.weight)", value: weightBinding(for: set), formatter: NumberFormatter())
}

// or as extension if you prefer:
extension MySet {
    var weightBinding: Binding<Int?> {
        Binding<Int?>(
            get: { self.weight },
            set: { value in
                if let value {
                    self.weight = value
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

TextField("\(set.weight)", value: set.weightBinding, formatter: NumberFormatter())


Like this you can clear the Textfield but if you don't enter a new value and stop editing it uses the last value.
EDIT:
If you want to set the value to 0 when the textfield is empty you need to change the Binding to this:

 Binding<Int?>(
         get: { set.weight },
         set: { value in
             self.weight = value ?? 0
          }
      )



it almost works but if the weight was 60 and I delete it and click to another Textfield the last value returns to 6 instead of 60

No I mean It was 60 and I removed the 60 and didnt type anything, then I clicked away to another textfield and instead of returning to 60 it goes to 6, so this implementation doesn't work

How did you removed the 60?
value is 60 -> delete 0 -> value is 6 -> delete 6 -> textfield is empty -> leave textfield? Then it would have already saved the 6

@johnsmith I edited my answer to set the value to 0 when the textfield gets cleared.

I am not sure why your code is not working, it would help to have a minimal reproducible example to work from.
However, one way of reaching a solution would be to create a generic wrapper for a TextField. The wrapper can hold the shadow state variable and perform the copying from the optional to the non-optional.
Here is an attempt to implement such a wrapper. I have gone for the Textfield initializer that takes a ParseableFormatStyle:
struct ValueField<F>: View
where F: ParseableFormatStyle, F.FormatInput: Equatable, F.FormatOutput == String {
    private let titleKey: LocalizedStringKey
    @Binding private var value: F.FormatInput
    private let format: F
    private let prompt: Text?
    @State private var fieldVal: F.FormatInput?
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    init(
        _ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey,
        value: Binding<F.FormatInput>,
        format: F,
        prompt: Text? = nil
    ) {
        self.titleKey = titleKey
        self._value = value
        self.format = format
        self.prompt = prompt
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField(titleKey, value: $fieldVal, format: format, prompt: prompt)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onChange(of: fieldVal) { oldVal, newVal in
                if let newVal, newVal != value {
                    value = newVal
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: isFocused, initial: true) { oldVal, newVal in
                if newVal {
                    fieldVal = nil
                } else if fieldVal == nil {
                    fieldVal = value
                }
            }
    }
}

Example use:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var val: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            ValueField(
                "Weight",
                value: $val,
                format: .number,
                prompt: Text("Weight")
            )
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)

            TextField("Dummy", text: dummy)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .padding()
    }

    private var dummy: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: { "\(val)" },
            set: { _ in /* NOP */ }
        )
    }
}



onChange is designed for external actions it's not the best tool for transforming state, computed vars are better for that

@malhal I don't see how any of the .onChange cases in the answer could be replaced by computed vars and still work the same way (with immediate updates in response to actions). Could you elaborate?

@malhal I saw how you used a computed Binding in your recent answer and can see how this could be applied to the example of use, answer updated. The example was just using the second TextField as a way to switch focus, so it wasn't really a big deal. But I still don't see, how even a computed Binding can be used in the wrapper struct. Please enlighten me.

Computed binding is for transforming stats types for this kind of limiting length didSet might be better

Without some more details and a minimum reproducible example, it's hard to provide a concrete answer. But, I think I understand your confusion, so let me offer some perspective.
I assume the purpose of editing textfields is because you're editing exercise sets. Normally, it would go something like this:

Pass exercise set to editor
On appear, the editor loads the exercise data into its own state variables (that are bound to the editor's textfields)
Edit the textfields at will
When done editing, hit save
The save function would copy the field values back to the exercise set.

An example of this approach can be found in Apple's tutorial on editing persisted data.
So the idea is you wouldn't bind the form fields directly to your data objects, which gives you the control to clear it or modify it as needed.
Below there's some working code that illustrates this. Note the ExerciseSetEditor form, its .onAppear method and the save function.

import SwiftUI

@Observable class ExerciseSet: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var weight: Int
    var reps: Int
    var isCompleted: Bool
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, weight: Int, reps: Int, isCompleted: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.reps = reps
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
    }
    // var exercise: Exercise // <-- commented out since not provided by OP
}

extension ExerciseSet {
    
    static let set1: ExerciseSet = ExerciseSet(name: "First set", weight: 5, reps: 10, isCompleted: false)
    static let set2: ExerciseSet = ExerciseSet(name: "Second set", weight: 10, reps: 5, isCompleted: false)
    
    static var sets: [ExerciseSet] = [set1, set2]
}

//Main view
struct ExerciseSetView: View {
    
    @State private var sets = ExerciseSet.sets
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //List sets
        List {
            ForEach(sets) { set in
                ExerciseSetRow(set: set)
            }
        }
        .listRowSpacing(20)
    }
}

//List row
struct ExerciseSetRow: View {
    
    @State var set: ExerciseSet
    
    @State private var showEditor = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            
            // Completion button
            Button {
                set.isCompleted.toggle()
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: set.isCompleted ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            
            //Set details
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(set.name)
                Text("Weight: \(set.weight), Reps: \(set.reps)")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            // Set config button
            Button {
                showEditor.toggle()
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showEditor) {
            NavigationStack {
                ExerciseSetEditor(set: set)
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}

//Editor
struct ExerciseSetEditor: View {
    
    @State var set: ExerciseSet?
    
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var weight: Int = 0
    @State private var reps: Int = 0
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            
            //Form title
            Text("Edit \(name)")
                .font(.title)
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            
            //Weight row
            HStack {
                Text("Weight:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                Spacer()
                TextField("Weight", value: $weight, format: .number)
                    .frame(width: 80)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Stepper("Weight", value: $weight, in: 3...20)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .scaleEffect(0.8)
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
            
            //Reps row
            HStack {
                Text("Reps:")
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                Spacer()
                TextField("Reps", value: $reps, format: .number)
                    .frame(width: 80)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Stepper("Reps", value: $reps, in: 3...20)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .scaleEffect(0.8)
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        }
        .onAppear { // <-- Here, initialize form fields with values from set object
            if let set = set {
                name = set.name
                weight = set.weight
                reps = set.reps
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            
            //Save button
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("Save"){
                    save()
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            
            //Cancel button
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                Button("Cancel"){
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Save form
    func save() {
        
        //Unwrapping
        guard let set = set else { return }
        
        //Copy the form values into the ExerciseSet object
        set.weight = weight
        set.reps = reps
        
    }
}



//Preview
#Preview {
    ExerciseSetView()
}

